# Função void com Spring retornando null no Angular 6

Tags: spring, angular-6

Tenho o seguinte código para apenas excluir um registro no banco e que deveria devolver um resultado com o status 204-OK.

Utilizo Spring Rest no back e um método como void com uma anotação @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT). Testei no Postman e ele retorna normal o resultado, e no navegador também aparece o resultado esperado. Porém, no código só retorna null.

O registro é excluído nessa função, está funcionando corretamente, porém o retorno 204 do backend não retorna para o Angular apenas. Não tenho a mínima ideia do que pode ser.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MasterHttp } from './../seguranca/master-http';
import { HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Tipo } from './../model/Tipo';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { environment } from './../../environments/environment';

export class TipoFilter {
  tipo: string;
  pagina = 0;
  itensPorPagina = 2;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TipoService {

  tiposUrl: string;

  constructor(private http: MasterHttp) {
    this.tiposUrl = `${environment.apiUrl}/tipos`;
  }



  excluir(id: number, posicaoDaPagina: number, itensPorPagina: number): Promise<any> {
    const dadosPagina = posicaoDaPagina + itensPorPagina - 1;

    const params = new HttpParams({
       fromObject: {
          page: `${dadosPagina}`,
          size: '1'
       }
    });

    return this.http.delete<any>(`${this.tiposUrl}/${id}`)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        let proximoObjeto;
        if (response.ok) {
           proximoObjeto = this.buscarProximo(params, dadosPagina);
        } else {
           return null;
        }
        return proximoObjeto;
      });

 }

  buscarProximo(params, dadosPagina): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.tiposUrl}`, { params })
    .toPromise()
    .then(resp => {
      const resultado = {
          lancamentos: resp.content,
          total: resp.totalElements
      };
      return (resultado.total + 1) < dadosPagina ? null : resultado;
    });
  }
}
```

No backend está assim:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/tipos")
public class TipoResource {

    @Autowired
    private TipoRepository tipoRepository;

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_CADASTRAR_TIPO')")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void remover(@PathVariable Long id) {
        tipoRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1**
Todas as funções que eu tenho funcionam no backend normalmente, inclusive essa de remover. Eu tenho essa exata função em outro projeto que funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Tente mudar o retorno de void para Object, se funcionar, eu publico a resposta

Comment: Tentei porém sem sucesso. Coloquei também retorno como ResponseEntity e uma String como body e mesmo assim continuou retornando null. Talvez o problema possa ser no backend, porém não consigo identificar.

Comment: Outros metodos sem ser delete estão funcionando?

Comment: Sim. Está tudo normal. O backend funciona corretamente, só o Angular que não está pegando essa resposta "OK 204" mesmo retornando ela.

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou retornar ResponseEntity ?

```
    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_CADASTRAR_TIPO')")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> remover(@PathVariable Long id) {
        tipoRepository.deleteById(id);
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html

Comment: Tentei, porém sem sucesso também.